# Select N rows in aggregate functions SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, partition

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------+------------+-------+
|   ID   | CHANNEL  | VENDOR | num_PERIOD | SALES |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+-------+
| 000001 | Business | Shop   |          1 | 40    |
| 000001 | Business | Shop   |          2 | 60    |
| 000001 | Business | Shop   |          3 | NULL  |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+-------+
```

With many combinations of `ID`, `CHANNEL` and `VENDOR`, and `sales` records for each of them over time (`num_PERIOD`).

The idea is to obtain a new column which returns the number of NULLS in `SALES` column, but in the first 111 registers according to `num_PERIOD` column.

I have been trying something like this:

```
SELECT ID,
       CHANNEL,
       VENDOR,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN SALES IS NULL THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID,
                                   CHANNEL,
                                   VENDOR
                      ORDER BY num_PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 111 FOLLOWING) AS NULL_SALES_SET
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID,
         CHANNEL,
         VENDOR
```

But I'm not obtaining what I'm looking for.

So to obtain a table simillar to:

```
+--------+--------------+--------+----------------+
|   ID   |   CHANNEL    | VENDOR | NULL_SALES_SET |
+--------+--------------+--------+----------------+
| 000001 | Business     | Shop   |              1 |
| 000002 | Business     | Market |              0 |
| 000002 | Non Business | Shop   |              3 |
+--------+--------------+--------+----------------+
```

The difficulty comes when selecting these first 111 rows per `ID`, `CHANNEL` AND `VENDOR` ordered by `num_PERIOD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use the windowing function?

```
SELECT ID
     , CHANNEL
     , VENDOR
     , NULL_SALES_SET = SUM(CASE WHEN SALES IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM Table
 WHERE num_PERIOD <= 111
 GROUP BY ID, CHANNEL, VENDOR
```

Or are you looking for the first 111 `num_PERIOD` values allowing for gaps in the `num_PERIOD` column?

```
SELECT t.ID
     , t.CHANNEL
     , t.VENDOR
     , NULL_SALES_SET = SUM(CASE WHEN t.SALES IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM Table t
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT i.ID
                          , i.CHANNEL
                          , i.VENDOR
                          , i.num_PERIOD
                          , rowNum = ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY i.ID, i.CHANNEL, i.VENDOR ORDER BY i.num_PERIOD)
                       FROM Table i ) l
          ON t.ID = l.ID
         AND t.CHANNEL = l.CHANNEL
         AND t.VENDOR = l.VENDOR
         AND t.num_PERIOD = l.num_PERIOD
 WHERE l.rowNum <= 111
 GROUP BY ID, CHANNEL, VENDOR
```

Edit: Not sure how I overlooked it, but it is necessary to JOIN on the num_PERIOD column.

Edit: Add the number of distinct `num_PERIOD` per ID, Channel, Vendor without affecting the NULL_SALES_SET

```
SELECT t.ID
     , t.CHANNEL
     , t.VENDOR
       -- Counts the NULL Sales when the num_PERIOD is in the 
       -- first 111 num_PERIODs
     , NULL_SALES_SET = SUM(CASE WHEN l.rowNum IS NOT NULL AND t.SALES IS NULL 
                                   THEN 1 
                                 ELSE 0 END)
       -- Counts the distinct num_PERIOD values
     , PERIOD_COUNT = COUNT(DISTINCT t.num_PERIOD)
  FROM Table t
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT i.ID
                               , i.CHANNEL
                               , i.VENDOR
                               , i.num_PERIOD
                               , rowNum = ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY i.ID,
                                                                  i.CHANNEL,
                                                                  i.VENDOR
                                                     ORDER BY i.num_PERIOD)
                          FROM Table i ) l
          ON t.ID = l.ID
         AND t.CHANNEL = l.CHANNEL
         AND t.VENDOR = l.VENDOR
         AND t.num_PERIOD = l.num_PERIOD
         AND l.rowNum <= 111
 GROUP BY ID, CHANNEL, VENDOR
```

Comment: This worked quite properly for the main purpose of the question 
However,I was wondering if the filter WHERE l.rowNum <= 111 is affecting any other calculation. For instance,imagine that algo I want to obtain the number of distinct a.num_PERIOD for one specific ID,CHANNEL,VENDOR. The real number of distinct num_PERIOD in my table is 139, but since I'm filtering with l.rowNum <= 111,the maximum number of period that I'm going to obtain is 111. Is there any way to use this filter only for the calculation of NULL_SALES_SET,and come back to the original table?

Comment: @Also - I am not following. Are you asking how to also include the number of distinct `num_PERIOD` for a given Id, Channel, Vendor?

Comment: sorry for the format of my comment. 
Yes, I'm wondering how to continue with other calculations without considering the filter in the where clause.
An example is calculating the total distincs of num_PERIOD for a given ID, CHANNEL, VENDER (but without limiting to the first 111 periods)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with the `ROW_NUMBER` windowed function and you should be set:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        id,
        channel,
        vendor,
        sales,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, channel, vendor ORDER BY num_period) AS row_num
    FROM
        MyTable
)
SELECT
    id,
    channel,
    vendor,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sales IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS null_sales_set
FROM
    MyCTE
WHERE
    row_num <= 111
GROUP BY
    id, channel, vendor
```

Comment: I like the use of the CTE - it cleans up the use of the table to just a single instance.